# Trying to filter a SQL query on a JSON field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables in PostgreSQL:

```
HomeSearch(id, client_id, name)
HomeSearchNote(id, homesearch_id, text)
Client(id, user_id)
User(id)
```

I'm trying to query HomeSearch and return a JSON as follows but only for those entries in HomeSearch for which the Client.user_id is equal to a certain value (say, 100):

```
HomeSearch {
  id:
  name:
  client: {
    id:
    user: {
      id
    }
  }
  notes: [{
    id:
    homesearch_id:
    text:
  },
  ...]
}
```

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
 *,
 ( SELECT row_to_json(client) from client where homeSearch.client_id=client.id ) client,
 ( SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(homeSearchNote)) from homeSearchNote where homeSearchNote.homesearch_id=homeSearch.id) notes
FROM homeSearch
WHERE client->>'user_id'=100
LIMIT 5;
```

However, this returns:

```
ERROR:  column "client" does not exist
LINE 19: WHERE client->>user_id=100
```

If I run the query without the WHERE clause in PGAdmin, I can clearly see a table with a 'client' column of type JSON.

Can anyone comment what would be the right way to place / write the WHERE clause ?

Much appreciated!

Comment: the problem is that the `client` column in the `client` table is not accessable in the `WHERE` clause as it is not present in the `From` part

Answer (score 0):

On way you can re-write the sql is as

```
With a as 
(SELECT *,
 ( SELECT row_to_json(client) from client where homeSearch.client_id=client.id ) client,

 ( SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(homeSearchNote)) from homeSearchNote where     homeSearchNote.homesearch_id=homeSearch.id) notes
FROM homeSearch
 )
 Select * from a WHERE client->>'user_id'=100
 LIMIT 5;
```